# Removing extra words from a column "Country"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to clean a COVID-19 dataset. There is a column called "Entity" which contains the names of the countries. A sample is shown below

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Entity</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Source URL</th>
      <th>Source label</th>
      <th>Cumulative total</th>
      <th>Daily change in cumulative total</th>
      <th>Cumulative total per thousand</th>
      <th>Daily change in cumulative total per thousand</th>
      <th>3-day rolling mean daily change</th>
      <th>3-day rolling mean daily change per thousand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Argentina - tests performed</td>
      <td>2020-04-08</td>
      <td>https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/fil...</td>
      <td>Government of Argentina</td>
      <td>13330</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>0.295</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Argentina - tests performed</td>
      <td>2020-04-09</td>
      <td>https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/fil...</td>
      <td>Government of Argentina</td>
      <td>14850</td>
      <td>1520.0</td>
      <td>0.329</td>
      <td>0.034</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Argentina - tests performed</td>
      <td>2020-04-10</td>
      <td>https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/fil...</td>
      <td>Government of Argentina</td>
      <td>16379</td>
      <td>1529.0</td>
      <td>0.362</td>
      <td>0.034</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Argentina - tests performed</td>
      <td>2020-04-11</td>
      <td>https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/fil...</td>
      <td>Government of Argentina</td>
      <td>18027</td>
      <td>1648.0</td>
      <td>0.399</td>
      <td>0.036</td>
      <td>1565.667</td>
      <td>0.035</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Argentina - tests performed</td>
      <td>2020-04-13</td>
      <td>https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/fil...</td>
      <td>Government of Argentina</td>
      <td>19758</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>0.437</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the column "Entity", there are extra words like "- tests performed" and I need to remove them so that I can merge them with the shapefile and visualize using Bokeh. Is there any way to just to remove the extra words?

Comment: Do the "extra words" always come with that hyphen? You could split on that, perhaps.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes. They start with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

If this "Entity" column always contains " - tests performed" then you can do this:

```
"Argentina - tests performed".replace(" - tests performed","")
```